# Format Hour in DB2?

Tags: db2

Is there any way to display db2 Hour function with AM and PM?

```
select hour(TIMESTAMP) from ORDERS with ur
```

This will give out like 5,6,7 etc..

But i want AM/PM after the Hour time.

I'd like to Dislpay as 5AM,6AM,7AM. Is it possible in db2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `TIME()` and `CHAR()` functions:

```
SELECT CHAR(TIME(timestamp), USA)
FROM Orders
WITH UR
```

Although, honestly, you should be doing this type of formatting in the application layer, not the SQL Layer.
(Statement run on my local DB2 instance)

---

## EDIT:

Sorry, I missed that part earlier.  Going through the documentation has shown me a new function, [VARCHAR_FORMAT()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0007110.html).  Assuming you're on DB2 9.5, the following should grant you some form of what you're looking for:

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(timestamp, 'HH12 AM')
FROM Orders
WITH UR
```

Unfortunately, I can't test this myself, as iSeries V6R1 doesn't support the `HH12` flag (`HH24` only, what?).  Otherwise, you're going to have to parse it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i developing simple batch so this is enough for me.

Comment: Please, at minimum, accept the answer you end up using (there should be a 'check-mark' under the voting count).  It's considered good etiquette to not leave questions 'hanging'.

Comment: This Query will give output as 10:00 PM, is it possible to print it as 10 PM?

Ok i'will do that

Comment: `HH` works the same as `HH12` in the format string. Also, you can use `AM` (or `PM`, either one) to print out AM or PM.

Comment: @bhamby - Ah, thank you.  That wasn't listed in the format specifier, so I didn't know if that was 'required' either.  Of course, the `AM` flag doesn't work for me either...