# Time format in DB2

Tags: time, db2

```
SELECT CHAR(TIME(timestamp), USA)
FROM Orders
WITH UR
```

This query will give output as 10:30 PM

Is it possible to display it as 10 PM (Only Hour with AM/PM)?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652671/format-hour-in-db2

Comment: This is not the same Question. Both are Different!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not a duplicate question (which it looks like to me), try using:

```
SUBSTR(CHAR(TIME(timestamp), USA),1,2) CONCAT SUBSTR(CHAR(TIME(timestamp), USA),6)
```

If you're running a version of DB2 that doesn't yet have full needed support for `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT()` or `VARCHAR_FORMAT()`, you might create a function that performs the operations above. The function could later be replaced when native functions are available.